# How to edit and relaunch a terminated cluster on Amazon EMR?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I am new to AWS and Amazon EMR. I have created a new cluster with a custom Bootstrap script. When I launched the clulster, it terminated on failure of the Bootstrap script. I have now fixed my script, and want to relaunch theNow, in the EMR console I am not finding any option to re-launch the cluster!

I searched a lot online, but didn't find any help guiding to re-launch a terminated cluster. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the option to clone the cluster. it can even have the same name.

Comment: Clone info in docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/clone-console.html